# Visual reporting for Karate without Jenkins CI

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, circleci, web-api-testing, karate

I'm trying to get reporting working for Karate DSL, and it's proven a challenge because my team uses Circle CI instead of Jenkins. Cucumber reporting seems to only work for Jenkins.

I've had a look at this documentation, here:

https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report
https://github.com/jenkinsci/cucumber-reports-plugin

I was wondering if there is a circle friendly equivalent you could recommend? It'd be even better if the reports could be generated in the terminal. It's going to be a hard sell to convince my team to change CI tools just so I can implement a test framework.

Thanks!

Comment: if the answer helped, in keeping with Stack Overflow etiquette, do consider marking as "accepted" (and up-voting). thx !

Comment: I'm new to the site, so my upvote isn't showing yet! But I did mark your answer as accepted :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I suggest:

If you follow the [demo / doc instructions](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report) - you will get the HTML reports in say `target/cucumber-html-reports`, and this is "pure Maven and Java", no dependency on CircleCI at all so far.

Now all you need to do is somehow make these HTML reports accessible via the web. In Jenkins, there is an [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin). I am not familiar with CircleCI but a quick search suggests that there is a way to [expose links to build artifacts](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/build-artifacts/).

Also note that when you follow the demo, Java JUnit XML reports would *also* be output to `target/cucumber-reports`. It looks like CircleCI has [support for these](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/test-metadata/#maven-surefire-plugin-for-java-junit-results) which means that it should be able to derive the build pass/fail status and stats if configured right.

Also note that Karate now enables you to write custom reports: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773839/143475

EDIT: It seems that Circle CI plays well with Docker, so refer Karate's docs here for Docker recipes: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/docker/README.md

And I found a thread on Circle CI discussions that may be useful to work out how to integrate Karate: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/working-with-a-machine-executor/23304

There may be some tips in the answer and comments here: [Integrating Karate with Circleci (Config.yml)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50381851/143475)