# Integrating Karate with Circleci (Config.yml)

Tags: circleci, karate, circleci-2.0

I'm totally new with this CI stuff and was asked to use Circleci. I have been googling for some hours and still didn't get stuff clear on how I can integrate Karate with Circleci.

I'm using Gradle for dependencie so I'm pretty clueless on how to make my Karate tests running on Circleci.

Any good soul to help me out how can I config the .yml circleci file to run my Karate tests?

I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I retweeted this, hope someone responds: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/996919696434876416 | meanwhile not sure if the TravisCI config will help: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: Thanks for the help, Peter! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @RafaelPaz I would start with a docker image or Dockerfile for Karate if you already have one. If you do start with that then you and build out the rest of your test environment using this image. Also checkout the CircleCI docs https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/ you can also head over to the CircleCI discuss site & post questions here http://discuss.circleci.com/

Comment: @A.Rivera tks for your replying. I already post a question there but so far no one replied. Yeah, I'm able to create and run succefuly the test, but when I try to use Karate, it crashes. Here's when it crashes                                                     
"
      - run: gradle dependencies
      
      test:
      - run karate test
"

Comment: What version of CircleCI are you using 1.0 or 2.0?  You should be using 2.0 because the 1.0 configs are nearing end of life & will not be supported.

Comment: I'm using the 2.0 version. Thks for the tips mate

Comment: Also try prefixing your cmds with this text `cat /dev/null |` so your cmd should read like this `cat /dev/null | gradle dependencies test` and `cat /dev/null |karate test`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171194/discussion-between-a-rivera-and-rafael-paz).

Answer (score 1):

try prefixing your commands with this text `cat /dev/null |` so your cmd should read like this `cat /dev/null | gradle dependencies test` and `cat /dev/null |karate test`

Can you also post the Error when it's failing