# Publish Karate-Cucumber html reports over email

Tags: cucumber, report, karate

How to publish complete html reports generated by Karate-Cucumber  over e-mail?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Peter, your previous answer didn't resolve the issue , I kept it open until I figure out the root cause. I have updated the other question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what a continuous integration server is for, e.g. Jenkins, and that is what all teams normally do.

For example see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48414722/143475

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, I will keep this thread posted if I any face issues on the same