# Executing Karate Test via scheduler on Azure and sending reports via email

Tags: karate

How can I integrate my Karate package built in VS Code with Azure and run as Batch job and send reports as Emails via Azure Cloud?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello rajarshi, your question seems to be very broad and lacking of your tries. Could you please rephrase your question to be narrower and attach some of your code? Thanks!

Comment: HI Eugenio.. Sorry for the confusion. I was just how do i run the tests from a batch job?. I have taken the source code from bintray link and changed the feature file. Now if i want to run the tests through a batch job in Cloud.

PS - I dont have much working knowledge of Java so tried the one source i found and worked on it through VS Code

Comment: I have to say your question is very broad and you seem to be asking us to do your homework for you. can you read the answer here - and if you still have questions, please edit your question to be very specific: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48414722/143475

Comment: also look into azure's builtin steps. there is an email step and there is a publish junit report step.

Comment: thanks all.. i will try out the steps.. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Since you have stated that you do not have much knowledge in Java, it is best to work with the Karate standalone JAR file which is also ideal for cloud environments like Azure.
Karate standalone JAR: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#standalone-jar

Download the Karate jar from Bintray and with a command line script in Azure, you can use it to execute the feature files.

I don’t have any inputs on mailing the reports.