# How I can make the URL of my summary report public to share in Karate framework

Tags: api, automated-tests, karate

I want to share the summary report with my collaborator, but it is local

[image]

Comment: this is not in scope for karate, let me know if this answer makes it clear and then I will close this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48414722/143475

Comment: @PeterThomas Thank you very much. I'm going to try that.